# How do I get past the error when trying to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04.1

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, package-management

I receive the following: The software on this computer is up to date. However, Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS is now available (you have 14.04).

I click upgrade, I get the welcome screen and I click upgrade. I get the message third party sources disabled. I say close. Next I get the error:

```
Error authenticating some packages. It was not possible to authenticate some packages. See below for a list of unauthenticated packages.

lsb
```

I only have one choice, Close
How do I get by this error?